# Delete Duplicate rows in several Postgresql tables

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres database with several tables like table1, table2, table3. More than 1000 tables.

I imported all of these tables from a script. And apparently the script had issues to import.

Many tables have duplicate rows (all values exactly same).

I am able to go in each table and then delete duplicate row using Dbeaver, but because there are over 1000 tables, it is very time consuming.

Example of tables:

**table1**

```
name      gender     age
a         m          20
a         m          20
b         f          21
b         f          21
```

**table2**

```
fruit     hobby      
x         running
x         running
y         stamp
y         stamp
```

How can I do the following:

- Identify tables in postgres with duplicate rows.
- Delete all duplicate rows, leaving 1 record.

I need to do this on all 1000+ tables at once.

Comment: This would be easier to answer with some examples of the records you'd like to delete.

Comment: Hi @dang: for solution need to write a stored procedure where using table wise loops for removing duplicate records.

Comment: @JakeWorth added examples of tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to automate your deduplication of all table, you need to use `plpgsql` function where you can write dynamic queries to achieve it.

Try This function:

```
create or replace function func_dedup(_schemaname varchar) returns void as
$$
declare
_rec record;
begin

for _rec in select table_name from information_schema. tables where table_schema=_schemaname

loop
execute format('CREATE TEMP TABLE tab_temp as select DISTINCT * from '||_rec.table_name);
execute format('truncate '||_rec.table_name);
execute format('insert into '||_rec.table_name||' select * from tab_temp');
execute format('drop table tab_temp');
end loop;

end;
$$
language plpgsql
```

Now call your function like below:

```
select * from func_dedup('your_schema'); --
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5d96fcd6b87f4f2bfeebfc42f9b3f66c)

**Steps:**

1. Get the list of all tables in your schema by using below query and loop it for each table.

```
select table_name from information_schema. tables where table_schema=_schemaname
```

2. Insert all `distinct` records in a `TEMP TABLE`.
3. Truncate your main table.
4. Insert all your data from `TEMP TABLE` to main table.
5. Drop the `TEMP TABLE`. (here dropping temp table is important we have to reuse it for next loop cycle.)

**Note -** if your tables are very large in size the consider using `Regular Table` instead of `TEMP TABLE`.

Comment: Is there a way to find all the tables where I have duplicate rows?